# Shorter way to differentiate variables

Tags: php, ruby, variables

Does `PHP` have an option to mark a variable as an instance variable or class variable or local variable inside a class?

`Ruby` has the following options:

```
Local variable   ->  myvar
Instance variable->  @myvar 
Class variable   ->  @@myvar
```

Is there any such option in PHP other than this lengthy `$myvar`, `$this->myvar` and `self::$myvar`?

I asked like this because I'm from ruby on rails background. There it was so easy to handle variables like as i gave above. In PHP the variable handling style didn't felt so handy. So I referred a docs a lot times. But didn't find any so I asked if I missed any such option in the docs and anyone else may have noticed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no such options in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->variable; //class var
ClassName::variable; //static var
$variable; //local var
```

Other than the above there is no other way to declare a variable (unless you want to use constants `define('VARIABLE', "some constant");`)

Comment: "*other than this lengthy `$myvar`, `$this->myvar` and `self::$myvar`*"